# How can I change the location Steam saves games on?

Tags: steam

I want to change the location steam saves my games too.

How can I do that?

Comment: please, explain better what do you mean with "Steam games". Any game distributed through Steam or some specific games only?

Comment: You can't; there's no one place steam saves all your save games too, because most games create save files themselves. Steam doesn't even know where each game puts them. Foolishly, many game developers like to invent new and unexpected places to store you saved games, making it difficult to backup and move them. The exceptions are the new games that support **Steam Cloud** (once again, it's up to the game what goes into the Steam Cloud, but save files are usually included).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's no built in method to move only your games (SteamApps) directory.  Your best bet is to move your entire Steam installation to your desired location.  Valve has a support article that details the steps involved in the entire procedure, along with some important warnings:

[Moving a Steam Installation and Games](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=7418-YUBN-8129)

Comment: I have done this several times and it works like a charm.

Answer (score 9):

Use [mklink](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753194(WS.10).aspx) and symlink directories.  Create a symbolic link in Program Files\Steam that points to a steamapps directory somewhere else. I've done it 2 times successfully.

Also, I should note, that if you don't know your file system then I would ask for help in doing this.

Comment: That doesn't move it, it only makes a copy without taking up more space.

Comment: Yes, it does move it.  You move the steamapps dir to some other drive.  Then in the Program Files/Steam you put a symlink to that directory that contains the data.  The file inside of Program Files/Steam becomes just a pointer to the other location but, when Steam interacts with it, it sees only the data. So you have your data somewhere else and only a pointer inside of Program Files/Steam to that data.  I've already done it multiple times.

Comment: AFAIK, you can't mklink across drives in Windows.

Comment: I've done it on all local drives.  My old setup was a 10,000RPM boot drive/OS drive.  I had steam installed on there and then I had a 640GB SATA3 drive where I had my steamapps folder.  I used a symlink and it worked fine.

Comment: It's definitely not something someone who doesn't know what they're doing should try. Hardlinks (junctions in this case) are very badly supported by NTFS.

Comment: This is exactly what I do with 100s of games and terabytes of data, it is fully supported and has worked perfectly for several years.  `mklink /D /J Steam D:\Steam` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You can't individually. However, you can install Steam anywhere you want, and the save games will then go there. The easiest way would be to move the current directory, uninstall Steam and re-install is wherever you want it, then copy over the moved directory.

Granted, this won't make much of a difference unless you want them on another disk, but it's the only way.

Comment: Also note some games don't save inside the steam folder ( [source](http://forums.steampowered.com/forums/showthread.php?t=840657) )

Comment: True, but that has more to do with the specific games than with Steam.

Comment: Not all Steam games saves in steamapps folder. Actually the majority of them saves in folders inside your local profile "Document & Settings/" etc.